# Mule 4 OuterJoin and Create new Array

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I am on Mule 4 (dataweave 2.0) and my code is given below:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
var var1 = [
  {"ID": 1000, "ID_2": "ABC-1000"},
  {"ID": 2000, "ID_2": "DEF-2000"},
  {"ID": 3000, "ID_2": "GHI-3000"}
]
var var2 = [
  {"EID": "ABC-1000", "GUID": "A0F4960AE5E54459A1B1FB40297EF893"},
  {"EID": "DEF-2000", "GUID": "63F6A192988A4C0696B117E9AC080611"},
  {"EID": "GHI-3000", "GUID": "A0FB600FA73E4E3BBF1CB59AA6E92AEF"}
]
---
outerJoin(var1, var2, (obj) -> (obj.ID_2), (obj) -> (obj.EID))
```

The output that I get is:

```
[
  {
    "l": {"ID": 1000, "ID_2": "ABC-1000"},
    "r": {"EID": "ABC-1000", "GUID": "A0F4960AE5E54459A1B1FB40297EF893"}
  },
  {
    "l": {"ID": 2000, "ID_2": "DEF-2000"},
    "r": {"EID": "DEF-2000", "GUID": "63F6A192988A4C0696B117E9AC080611"}
  },
  {
    "l": {"ID": 3000, "ID_2": "GHI-3000"},
    "r": {"EID": "GHI-3000", "GUID": "A0FB600FA73E4E3BBF1CB59AA6E92AEF"}
  }
]
```

Expected output is shown below. I need to flatten both left and right outputs and also introduce a static attribute.

```
[
    {"Key1": "1000", "Key2": "ABC-1000", "Name": "Test", "GUID": "A0F4960AE5E54459A1B1FB40297EF893"},
    {"Key2": "2000", "Key2": "DEF-2000", "Name": "Test", "GUID": "63F6A192988A4C0696B117E9AC080611"},
    {"Key3": "3000", "Key2": "GHI-3000", "Name": "Test", "GUID": "A0FB600FA73E4E3BBF1CB59AA6E92AEF"}
]
```

Please advise.

Comment: If you want to perform an `outerJoin` you need to provide input and output data with rows that don't match.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, but note I changed your `outerJoin` to a `join`:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
var var1 = [
  {"ID": 1000, "ID_2": "ABC-1000"},
  {"ID": 2000, "ID_2": "DEF-2000"},
  {"ID": 3000, "ID_2": "GHI-3000"}
]
var var2 = [
  {"EID": "ABC-1000", "GUID": "A0F4960AE5E54459A1B1FB40297EF893"},
  {"EID": "DEF-2000", "GUID": "63F6A192988A4C0696B117E9AC080611"},
  {"EID": "GHI-3000", "GUID": "A0FB600FA73E4E3BBF1CB59AA6E92AEF"}
]
---
join(var1, var2, (obj) -> (obj.ID_2), (obj) -> (obj.EID))
reduce (e, acc=[]) -> (
    acc + {
        Key1: e.l.ID,
        Key2: e.l.ID_2,
        Name: "Test",
        GUID: e.r.GUID
    }
)
```

Describe what the output data look like in the absence of a matching record from either the left or the right side and then I would be able to switch back to `outerJoin`

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking can be done with a simple mapping after the outerJoin:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
var var1 = [
  {"ID": 1000, "ID_2": "ABC-1000"},
  {"ID": 2000, "ID_2": "DEF-2000"},
  {"ID": 3000, "ID_2": "GHI-3000"}
]
var var2 = [
  {"EID": "ABC-1000", "GUID": "A0F4960AE5E54459A1B1FB40297EF893"},
  {"EID": "DEF-2000", "GUID": "63F6A192988A4C0696B117E9AC080611"},
  {"EID": "GHI-3000", "GUID": "A0FB600FA73E4E3BBF1CB59AA6E92AEF"}
]
---
outerJoin(var1, var2, (obj) -> (obj.ID_2), (obj) -> (obj.EID)) 
map {
    "Key1": $.l.ID,
    "Key2" : $.l.ID_2,
    "Name": "Test", 
    ($.r - "EID")
}
```

wich gives:

```
[
  {
    "Key1": 1000,
    "Key2": "ABC-1000",
    "Name": "Test",
    "GUID": "A0F4960AE5E54459A1B1FB40297EF893"
  },
  {
    "Key1": 2000,
    "Key2": "DEF-2000",
    "Name": "Test",
    "GUID": "63F6A192988A4C0696B117E9AC080611"
  },
  {
    "Key1": 3000,
    "Key2": "GHI-3000",
    "Name": "Test",
    "GUID": "A0FB600FA73E4E3BBF1CB59AA6E92AEF"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need both matched and unmatched items in your use-case and **outerJoin** is the right option. If you are just looking for the matched keys then you should go with a simple **join**.

With outerJoin

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var var1 = [
  {"ID": 1000, "ID_2": "ABC-1000"},
  {"ID": 2000, "ID_2": "DEF-2000"},
  {"ID": 3000, "ID_2": "GHI-3000"},
  {"ID": 4000, "ID_2": "GHI-4000"}
]
var var2 = [
  {"EID": "ABC-1000", "GUID": "A0F4960AE5E54459A1B1FB40297EF893"},
  {"EID": "DEF-2000", "GUID": "63F6A192988A4C0696B117E9AC080611"},
  {"EID": "GHI-3000", "GUID": "A0FB600FA73E4E3BBF1CB59AA6E92AEF"},
  {"EID": "GHI-5000", "GUID": "A0FB600FA73E4E3BBF1CB59AA6E92AEF"}
]
output application/json
---
outerJoin(var1, var2, (var1) -> var1.ID_2, (var2)-> var2.EID) map {
    Key1: $.l.ID,
    Key2: $.l.ID_2,
    Name: "Test",
    GUID: $.r.GUID
}
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "Key1": 1000,
    "Key2": "ABC-1000",
    "Name": "Test",
    "GUID": "A0F4960AE5E54459A1B1FB40297EF893"
  },
  {
    "Key1": 2000,
    "Key2": "DEF-2000",
    "Name": "Test",
    "GUID": "63F6A192988A4C0696B117E9AC080611"
  },
  {
    "Key1": 3000,
    "Key2": "GHI-3000",
    "Name": "Test",
    "GUID": "A0FB600FA73E4E3BBF1CB59AA6E92AEF"
  },
  {
    "Key1": 4000,
    "Key2": "GHI-4000",
    "Name": "Test",
    "GUID": null
  },
  {
    "Key1": null,
    "Key2": null,
    "Name": "Test",
    "GUID": "A0FB600FA73E4E3BBF1CB59AA6E92AEF"
  }
]
```

With join

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var var1 = [
  {"ID": 1000, "ID_2": "ABC-1000"},
  {"ID": 2000, "ID_2": "DEF-2000"},
  {"ID": 3000, "ID_2": "GHI-3000"},
  {"ID": 4000, "ID_2": "GHI-4000"}
]
var var2 = [
  {"EID": "ABC-1000", "GUID": "A0F4960AE5E54459A1B1FB40297EF893"},
  {"EID": "DEF-2000", "GUID": "63F6A192988A4C0696B117E9AC080611"},
  {"EID": "GHI-3000", "GUID": "A0FB600FA73E4E3BBF1CB59AA6E92AEF"},
  {"EID": "GHI-5000", "GUID": "A0FB600FA73E4E3BBF1CB59AA6E92AEF"}
]
output application/json
---
join(var1, var2, (var1) -> var1.ID_2, (var2)-> var2.EID) map {
    Key1: $.l.ID,
    Key2: $.l.ID_2,
    Name: "Test",
    GUID: $.r.GUID
}
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "Key1": 1000,
    "Key2": "ABC-1000",
    "Name": "Test",
    "GUID": "A0F4960AE5E54459A1B1FB40297EF893"
  },
  {
    "Key1": 2000,
    "Key2": "DEF-2000",
    "Name": "Test",
    "GUID": "63F6A192988A4C0696B117E9AC080611"
  },
  {
    "Key1": 3000,
    "Key2": "GHI-3000",
    "Name": "Test",
    "GUID": "A0FB600FA73E4E3BBF1CB59AA6E92AEF"
  }
]
```